# Cannot Install Google Chrome

Tags: installation, internet, browser

I am having trouble installing Google Chrome on my Ubuntu 11.10 system. After downloading it from http://www.google.com/chrome I am trying to open it with a double click. Software Center pops up, I see the loading wheel, then I get a message that the package cannot be opened. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're talking about chromium or chrome?

Comment: try chromium from the app store

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fire up a terminal using Control+Alt+T, then write:

```
sudo dpkg --install /Path/to/chrome.deb
```

Ignore the errors, then:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then again:

```
sudo dpkg --install /Path/to/chrome.deb
```

The Google Chrome package is missing dependencies; this installs those dependencies. You should be able to install the package.

Comment: Also, all of these answers do essentially the same thing, just in different ways.

Comment: Wait, why would you need to run the `sudo dpkg -i` command again? I never do that and it works fine

Answer (score 5):

Open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

In order to install Google Chrome you have to run this command in the terminal :

sudo apt-get install libxss1 libnspr4-0d libcurl3

Or just manually install those 3 packages :

- libxss1
- libnspr4-0d
- libcurl3

And then you can install Google Chrome (I've got the same problem at my first install).

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Not Really, It Didn't Work.

Comment: Strange... When I try to install Google Chrome after a fresh install of Ubuntu the same error always appears using Ubuntu Software Center to install it or "dpkg", those packages are not present and I need to install them manually so usually what I do is this : 1 - "sudo apt-get install libxss1 libnspr4-0d libcurl3" and then 2 - "sudo dpkg -i google_chrome.deb" and it works

Answer (score 1):

It might be caused by missing packages in your repository. Try to switch to the main server.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Download_Server

Then re-run update-manager and install any updates.

I had a similar problem with Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I got the libxss1 deb from here and installed manually: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libxss1/download

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing Chrome using the PPA. This can be done two ways.

### Simple Way

You can run this bash script, which just wraps the hard way up in a nutshell.

```
wget http://mtweb.site90.com/files/chrome.sh
bash chrome.sh
```

For more info, see [Millhousen Tech's Tech-To](http://mtweb.site90.com/tech-tos/install-chrome-linux-terminal/).

### Long Way

The bash script contains the following commands that you can run. (Exact same as simple way, just longer.)

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
sudo apt-get update
```

You can then choose what version of Chrome you want to install. Stable, Beta, or Unstable. (Run one of the following commands.)

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable

sudo apt-get install google-chrome-beta

sudo apt-get install google-chrome-unstable
```

For more info, see [How Open Source's website](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/10/install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-11-10-11-04-10-10-10-04/).