# Google Chrome Installation failed

Tags: installation, google-chrome

Despite my best efforts I cannot get google chrome to work on Ubuntu. It's probably due to the fact that I'm not good at terminal commands, but help would be greatly appreciated.

I've downloaded the correct version of Google Chrome for my computer, and I've tried going to Home -- Downloads and double clicking on the downloaded file. It comes up in the software center as an internal error and the file cannot be opened.

I've also tried to write or create the correct paths using the steps mentioned in [this help thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68724/cannot-install-google-chrome)
I was following these steps --->

```
sudo dpkg --install /Path/to/chrome.deb
```

Ignore the errors, then:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then again:

```
sudo dpkg --install /Path/to/chrome.deb
```

When I place that into the terminal I also get errors It says

> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 447 not upgraded

Comment: Go to google and download chrome.

Comment: I went directly to google and downloaded the correct version, didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68724/cannot-install-google-chrome

Comment: Read that too, tried it, no luck still doesn't install

Comment: Why not? we don't know what output you get, add it to your question.

Comment: @Jenne Your answer have poor information. You should add more information like screenshots or commands entered.

Comment: Okay I'm trying I don't know how to enter screenshots though. I just think I'm writing in the terminal incorrectly.

Comment: I took the first step first and entered this into terminal ---> sudo dpkg -install /Path/to/chrome.deb the result is this--->  dpkg: error: unknown option -n I'm following the first solution in this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/68724/cannot-install-google-chrome

Comment: You did change the Path to where the chrome deb is located, right? don't complicate yourself, just open the deb file with the Software Center.

Comment: I tried to open the downloaded software in the Center, it says there is an internal error and the file cannot be opened.

Answer (score 1):

You said [in this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170178/google-chrome-installation-failed#comment209323_170178) that you ran `sudo dpkg -install /Path/to/chrome.deb` and got an error `dpkg: error: unknown option -n`.

As with most (though not all) commands, a single dash before a sequence of letters designates all the short (i.e., one letter long) options corresponding to each letter, whereas two dashes before a sequence of letters designates that the whole sequence is to be construed as a single, long (i.e., word-like) option.

So you should be running **one of these commands instead**:

- `dpkg -i /Path/to/chrome.deb`
- `dpkg --install /Path/to/chrome.deb`

Use either one, they're equivalent. (See [`man dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dpkg.1.html) if you want details.)

Running `dpkg -install /Path/to/chrome.deb` is wrong because it's equivalent to `dpkg -i -n -s -t -a -l -l /Path/to/chrome.deb`. (That's why you get an error about `dpkg` doesn't know what to do with a `-n` option.)

Comment: Okay, I fixed that error but the terminal still says that errors were encountered In the last step for some reason. After I ran --install /Path/to/chrome.deb it says that it successfully read and built the dependency tree and package lists then it goes on to say 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 447 not upgraded. =[ then I ran the very last step sudo dpkg /Path/to/chrome.deb and it says "Errors were encountered while processing: /Path/to/chrome.deb

Comment: @Jenne The information necessary to solve this is probably too long to provide in comments; also, comments don't keep the formatting necessary to understand the output. Please copy *all the text* from the Terminal, paste it into your question (by editing your question), and use the `<$>` tool to format it properly. If you've already closed the Terminal window where you did this, you can do it again to get the text to copy.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try installing chromium?

Its almost the same. You can find it in the software center.

Comment: Understood. Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: That's okay. I removed my downvote.